# Creating launcher icon to Google Play Store's "Manage apps & device" page (preferably in Nova launcher)

Tags: google-play-store, updates, 7.0-nougat, launcher, nova-launcher

I had a home screen icon to the "Manage apps & device" page in Google Play Store.  Specifically, I had this set up in Nova Launcher (Prime).

I tried to recall how I accomplished this, and I simply do not recall, as it was several years ago.

Looking at the Nova Launcher backup file, I see that I had a shortcut to `action=com.google.android.finsky.VIEW_MY_DOWNLOADS`.  Yet when I go to the `Activities` list for the Google Play Store, I do not see this activity.

How can one setup a launcher icon to directly access the Google Play Store's "Manage apps & device" page?  Alternatively, the "Pending downloads" page might be acceptable as well.

To avoid accidentally posting an XY question, my goal is to quickly see what apps that were downloaded from the Google Play Store have available updates (and download updates if desired).  The device is running Android Nougat and has auto-updates disabled.

---

***Edit:***
The reason why I am interested in how I previously set up this Nova Launcher icon is that I want to open the "Manage apps & device" page as a "tap" (single-click) behaviour on a folder icon.  Specifically, Nova allows creating a launcher icon for a folder that uses "swipe to open" to open the folder, and specifying a "tap action" when tapping on the icon.  (A bug in Nova appears to prevent enabling "swipe to open" while having no "tap action".)

For the "tap action", the user can select almost anything, including any available shortcut or any available `activity` (but not manually entering an `activity` string).  I just want to figure out how to specify opening the "Manage apps & device" page for the "tap action".

Answer (score 1):

- Long-Press on the Play Store shortcut.
- `My Apps` will be among the option shown. Long press on it to move it to your screen an create a shortcut.
- Press the icon to open `Manage apps & device`.

Comment: Thanks Reddy.  I knew it must had been something so obvious I wasn't seeing it.  One of the challenges of SE is to provide sufficient details without overwhelming people.  I erred on the side of not overwhelming others, which has caused your excellent answer to not work for what I'm trying to accomplish.  If I edit my question, would you mind taking another look?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket using this activity `com.google.android.finsky.VIEW_MY_DOWNLOADS` via Automate opens the desired Play store page. Do you want to launch it from Nova launcher?

Comment: Yes, but I want to launch it for the "tap action" on a folder, for which the user can select any available `shortcut` or `activity`.